# Hole density kinetic energy $=E-E_v$

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

According to these [notes](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee130/fa13/Notes.pdf), page 2, (and other places I have looked) the kinetic energy of a hole is given by:
$$KE=E_v-E$$
Where $E_v$ is the valance band edge energy and $E$ is the total energy. This formula seems to indicate that as the kinetic energy increases the total energy decreases. Please can someone explain this to me?

I think it is something to do with the effective mass $m^*_h$ of the hole, however, different sources use different definitions (and signs) for this mass making it even more confusing.

Comment: The higher the kinetic energy of a hole, the further below the top of the valence band it is. This tends to (does) ignore actual band structure, and thus any mention of the effective mass.

Comment: @JonCuster even so, this does not explain why increasing the kinetic energy of the hole (and leaving everything else) decreases its total energy.

Comment: Consider the electron case - the kinetic energy is $E-E_{c}$, correct? Holes are, well, upside down electrons...